# perl number of combination or permutation

Tags: perl, combinations

I want to calculate the number of combinations when given some number, e.g number of combinations when 5 choose from 10. But the `Math::Combinatorics` module gives you the combination lists when given character set. Is there such a module or I need to use factorial functions to represent it when programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math::Combinatorics` and count the size of the returned list. However, a better module would be [`Math::Counting`](http://search.cpan.org/~gene/Math-Counting-0.0908/lib/Math/Counting.pm).

```
use Math::Counting ':big';
printf "C(10, 5) = %d\n", bcomb(10, 5);
```